# Do we need to run Optimize command after bulk delete to balance the index?

Tags: mysql

I am going to delete records in bulk. Do we need to run Optimize command on table to reclaim the index space ?

If I want to delete the records in batches, what should be the optimal batch size and how to decide that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to balance the index?

No.

> to reclaim the space?

Yes.

These aren't the same thing.

Comment: I got the difference. how to quantify the batch size ?